# Google Search Console and Html tags

Tags: xml, phtml, ee-1.13

I have 2 questions, I am new to Magento but not to programming in general.

- Where do i change html content like H1, H2 in home page, products
  page, etc. I noticed the difference between cms and category but what
  i see inside the panel are either xml or references to Phtml? Where
  do i find common Html structure with footer, header, etc?
- Where do i setup code like the one requiered in Google Search Console
  to function?

Thank you and regards :)

Answer (score 0):

For magento template file structure, you can head to these folders:

> app/code/design/frontend/your_theme/template

**Product:**

Simple/configurable:

> app/code/design/frontend/your_theme/template/catalog/product

Bundle:

> app/code/design/frontend/your_theme/template/bundle/catalog/product

**Footer/Header**

> app/code/design/frontend/your_theme/template/page/html

**CMS**

> app/code/design/frontend/your_theme/template/cms

This is the basic folder/file structure. Good luck.

**You can also get the exact file hint for each page by doing this:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint

Remember, this is not recommended in live site, you should only test in production environment, so that your customer doesn't get some weird looking text.

Comment: Hi Adarsh/Rohan, i dont see the option developer under advanced. To activate the path. Its same thing in Magento enterprise? I am using that.

Comment: There are two `Advanced`. Parent Advanced and then it's child Advanced.